# Open many credit cards while I am young?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit, credit-history

I just turned 19 years old and want to start planning for a future of good credit. Should I open many credit cards now so that in 10 years I will have a good history with many agencies, or is it actually bad for my credit to open so many cards at once? Will I be setting myself up for failure by accruing too big of a cumulative credit card bill?

Comment: The role of credit score and what to do to improve it varies a lot from country to country. So please add a country-tag to your question. If I had to guess I would say "United States", because other countries are usually far less interested in how credit card usage affects credit worthiness, but that would still be a guess.

Comment: I recommend reading this https://money.stackexchange.com/a/73653/20835 to get a better understanding of how to properly use a credit card.  As it mentions, building credit score is *not* really the main goal of having a credit card, and having multiple will not be substantially additive to your credit score.

Comment: You can have multiple cards *without* "accruing too big of a cumulative credit card bill". You're right that your average age (a significant portion of your credit score) would benefit from this in the long-term, but it's not necessary to pay even a penny in interest to accomplish this. I have 10+ cards, but I haven't paid a cent in interest on any of them.

Comment: You don't need lots of cards to be listed by many agencies. There are really only 3 credit reporting agencies that matter (in the US) Experian, TransUnion, and Equifax, and they all get the same raw data.

Comment: You can have the cards without using them, and if you don't use them you don't have to pay the  bill (if there aren't any fees).

Comment: @Barmar "Being listed" and "having an optimal score" aren't the same, though. A [thick file - five or more lines of credit](https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/what-is-a-thin-credit-file-and-how-will-it-impact-your-life/) is both more resilient to changes (like having a bank close one of your accounts or lower your available credit) and looks better to lenders.

Comment: @Pete B.: Having many credit cards does not mean you have to give much of your income, or indeed, ANY of your income, to banks.  I have half a dozen or so cards (a legacy of the days when they gave you money to sign up for them), with a cumulative credit limit pushing 6 figures, yet have never given the issuers a cent.  Indeed, the ones I use give me money :-)

Comment: I have a section on how to use credit card in one of my other Answers. https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/102603/paying-off-debt-and-living-within-means-vs-long-term-planning/102615#102615

Comment: @computercarguy Indeed, and maybe consistent good history across many cards produces a better score than just having one card with a good history.

Comment: @Barmar, yes and no. My Answer focused on how not to hurt yourself with CCs. It's all too easy to get into bad habits with them, which I know from experience. And it only takes a couple of bad moves to erase the good work you've done. Also, credit takes into account how much credit you already have access to, so having multiple CCs can reduce the amount of credit offered by a new company. Creditors don't want to take the chance you'll max out everything and not be able to pay them while you pay off other stuff. CCs are definitely a double-edged sword that many people get cut on.

Comment: @jamesqf there are still plenty of cards that will pay you to get them.  Most of the good ones have annual fees so they're only worth keeping for a year.  That being said, Chase offers $200 for one of their free Freedom variants.

Comment: I suppose this in the US? Credit rating is not a thing in Germany for example (plus, we love cash and think everything that bears the name "credit" is a slippery slope towards excessive debt).

Comment: @Dean MacGregor: Thanks, but alas, I already have the Chase card :-(

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica what about for something like a house though?

Comment: Not about credit score, but another consideration:  I had an acquaintance who took out a bunch of CC's as soon as he graduated high school.  He bragged about how he never used them.  Then he went to buy a house a couple years later and was turned down for a loan:  Because, while he had zero balances on all cards, he had the _potential_ to instantly borrow $24,000, which was close to the value of the home (in Nebraska in the 1970's.)  The bank wouldn't risk it.  There are other things besides credit scores.

Comment: @Kat that's (partly) an investment. I thought more of day-to-day consumption spending.

Answer (score 39):

> I just turned 19 years old and want to start planning for a future of good credit.

A laudable goal.

> Should I open many credit cards now so that in 10 years I will have a good history with many agencies,

No.

> or is it actually bad for my credit to open so many cards at once?

Yes.

> Will I be setting myself up for failure by accruing too big of a cumulative credit card bill?

You must understand that a Credit Score is nothing but "their" estimate of your reliability in **paying your bills on time**.

Thus, it should be quite obvious that spending so much that you rack up giant CC bills is contraindicated to "good credit".

**Two** credit cards are all you need:

- One that you regularly use, and
- One that's a spare in case you lose the other (or it gets stolen).

To summarize, the two simple rules for having a great credit score:

1. Pay your bills (all of them!) **fully** and **on time** each month.
2. Ensure that the each month's CC bill is [less than 10% of your credit limit](https://www.cnbc.com/select/what-is-a-good-credit-utilization-ratio/).  If you make total purchases above 10% of your limit, pay part of it off before the end of the billing period.

It's that simple, that boring, and boils down to "live below your means".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117139/discussion-on-answer-by-ronjohn-open-many-credit-cards-while-i-am-young).

Comment: Two cards, yes.  I suggest that you make the limit no higher than you can max out and pay off in full.   A third card with a higher limit, that you keep in your freezer, used only for emergencies can also be helpful.

Comment: In my experience with US credit reporting bureaus, paying off the balance each month doesn't ameliorate the negative consequences of a high credit used:credit available ratio, which makes up a very significant part of the score. They look at your credit utilization at some arbitrary point in time, not at the end of the billing cycle.

Comment: Anecdote: for the longest time, I had only one credit card, even well into adulthood, with a $500 limit. I used it for normal expenses and paid it off in full every month. But when I bought my first house, my credit score was was is the 500s, largely because my credit utilization ratio was high. It is not hard to spend $500/mo. I opened another card and they gave me a higher limit. Then I opened a few more. My spending and payment habits have not changed, but now my credit score is in the 800s, just because my utilization ratio is less.

Comment: @PhilFrost It seems then that the credit scoring algorithm is absolutely stupid, if you can manipulate it to your advantage by taking out more credit cards.

Comment: @gnasher729 isn't that exactly what OP is thinking about?

Comment: @gnasher729 just because it's stupid doesn't make it not so.

Comment: @gnasher729 it must be asked whether PhilFrost's score would be in the 800s if he'd only opened **one** more card.  We don't know, and neither does he.  (I've got four cards, but **rarely** use two of them; could probably drop them, but don't see the need.)

Comment: @gnasher729 not really. It's an amalgam of your behavior and how much you are trusted by creditors. If you were trusted enough to have [however much] credit, and you are using it responsibly, the score correctly reflects that.

Comment: @RonJohn that is a question to ask, but your answer goes further to say that OP *should not* open many cards and that doing so is bad. It supposes that we *do* know. Also, it's easier to ensure less than 10% (total) utility if you have more utility.

Comment: @fectin just remember that their definition of using CCs "responsibly" (pay on time and keep usage rate below some unstated percentage) is noticeably different from the personal finance definition of responsible CC usage (pay your cards off fully and on time).

Comment: @RonJohn oh, definitely. But they're not measuring your future happiness or financial health, they're measuring risk of not getting paid.

Comment: @Corey "Two credit cards are all you need" is subtly but **importantly different** from "you should not open more than two cards".

Comment: [citation needed] for that 10% claim.

Comment: @Braiam citation link added.

Comment: @PhilFrost true, but your credit utilization history has no effect, only whatever was last reported, so just keep your balance low if you're going to apply for credit soon. Use a debt card instead for a month, pay off the CC every time you make a purchase, or whatever makes sense for you. It does require some planning though.

Comment: @gnasher729 why's that stupid? Imagine you have a friend who borrows ten dollars at a time and reliably pays it back as agreed. Then they ask you for $1000. Would your previous history be enough to feel comfortable loaning that much? Same thing here, if you want to borrow a lot, it helps if you can show others have already trusted you with that amount and you haven't abused it.

Comment: @Kat the last part of your comment confuses me.  Why use a DC for a month if your utilization rate is low?

Comment: @Kat Massage the scenario just slightly. Suppose your friend asks you if he can borrow $1000 every once in a while, and you say yes. But then, every month, they only ask for $10, and then reliably pay that back. Doesn't it seem a bit stupid to suddenly trust them more now than back when they correctly predicted that they would need only $10/month?

Comment: @DanielWagner your conclusion seems a bit backwards.  "Your friend" was occasionally asking for -- and repaying -- $1000, **and then** started asking for -- and repaying -- just $10/ every month.  I would *definitely* trust someone regularly with $10 than occasionally with $1000 even if they had always repaid the $1000 on time.

Comment: @RonJohn No, that's not how credit cards work. First you say the maximum you ever want to borrow (in my example, $1000). Then you start borrowing, and you may never hit that maximum (in my example, $10/mo). There's no initial run-in period where my friend actually borrowed $1000. It is stupid that because he declared $1000 as the maximum, he is more trusted than the person that declared $20 as their maximum and had the same borrowing/payback activity. And that is how credit scores work.

Comment: @DanielWagner since I know exactly how credit cards work, it must be your example which is flawed, leading me to misinterpret it.  Specifically, "*Suppose your friend asks you if he can borrow $1000 every once in a while, and you say yes.*"  To me, that means you occasionally loaned him $1000.  If you really meant ""*Suppose your friend asks you if he can borrow **UP TO** $1000* every once in a while", then you should have written that.

Comment: @PhilFrost: best action would have been to get the old account to raise your credit limit, same history, lower utilization, no recent accounts.  Even better, there’s at least a chance they would do so without a hard pull.

Comment: @RonJohn Now that you understand what I meant, don't you agree that it's kind of stupid?

Comment: @jmoreno True that may be technically better, assuming I actually wanted to use that card (I didn't) and they would actually raise my credit limit by as much as a new card would. But in practice new accounts and hard pulls are pretty insignificant as long as everything else is good (if you open new accounts then immediately max them out, not so much). Remember the industry _wants_ to have a card or twenty: so much so they will _pay_ you to open one!

Answer (score 17):

Your credit score is devised by 5 components.

1. Age of account
2. Credit utilization
3. Payment history
4. New Credit
5. Credit mix

https://www.myfico.com/credit-education/whats-in-your-credit-score

If you get a new credit card then that will be a negative mark under the new credit category.  That negative mark only lasts as long as that card is actually new.  However, after some time, that card will be beneficial to you in the age of account category and will no longer be negative in the new account category.  Further, since credit utilization looks at the ratio of how much you owe to your aggregate credit limit, having more credit helps that category.

The preceding paragraph makes an assumption that you will not spend differently when you get an extra card.  If you think opening lots of cards will result in your spending more money than you otherwise would then you can throw the above out the window.

If you do end up with several cards, it doesn't do you any good to spread the spending out amongst them.  You can just stick them safely in a drawer and use your favorite one for day to day needs.  One caveat here is that some cards will close your account after a certain stretch of inactivity but they'll usually warn you first.  The main thing is to avoid paying fees and interest which means to pay your balance each month regardless of the number of cards and don't open cards with annual fees.  As long as you stick to paying off your balance each month then the stated APR doesn't matter because you only pay interest on balances that you carry.

Comment: As opposed to other answers - this is to the point.  There is no long term harm in opening 10 cards (if you can manage that) assuming you don't abuse it.  Hard pulls drop off.  If anything multiple cards is beneficial.  Age of account is an average.  When you open new credit down the line, the more older cards, the better.

Comment: Agreed. I think this point is important enough to repeat: if your spending habits don't change by opening another card, the negative consequences of the hard pull are more than outweighed by the positive consequences of decreasing your utilization ratio, by having more unused credit available. If you have $500 of credit, and spent $300/mo, and pay it off in full every month, your credit will be mediocre at best due to the high utilization ratio. Makes no sense, but that's how it is.

Comment: So it seems if you don't spend more, opening 10 cards is actually a good move? It also seems the higher the limit on these cards, the better the move because it lowers your utilization ratio even more. From my belgian perspective it sounds crazy...

Comment: @LaurentS. At some point you're going to hit diminishing returns pretty hard and I'd guess it's before 10 cards but yes.

Comment: @LaurentS. It seems irrational to me too, with a US perspective. Unfortunately I don't love any of the answers here, but: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/33812/why-is-a-us-credit-score-based-on-credit-utilization

Answer (score 9):

I'm slightly concerned about the wording you used in this sentence:

> Will I be setting myself up for failure by accruing too big of a cumulative credit card bill?

Maybe you didn't intend to word it that way, but it sounds as though you're thinking that if you simply have one or more credit cards, you might spend more money than you normally would, and therefore end up not being able to pay it off right away. This leads to debt and interest, and can be a vicious cycle that takes years, or even a lifetime to get out of. If you feel this could be the case for you, then I would strongly urge you to hold off on getting a credit card until you are confident it won't be a problem.

But if you are sure that the act of having one or more credit cards will not change your spending habits, then there are some worthwhile benefits to getting at least one credit card. (E.g. cashback, purchase protection, additional insurance and warranties on certain items.)

As to whether multiple credit cards will help your credit score more than just having a single card, I'd say yes, slightly, but only if most of the credit is unused- but if it's unused you don't really need it! Of course it's certainly OK to have credit you don't need, **IF** you won't be tempted to spend it. In the future, what will matter more is the utilization percentage. For example, if you have 3 credit cards with a $5K limit, and if your total spend at a specific moment is $1K, then your score wouldn't differ that much if it is instead a single card with a $15K limit. It's possible that having multiple cards today will lead to a higher total limit in 10 years than if it was just 1 card, and it may also benefit from a higher AAoA when you get a new account. But IMHO the slight benefit of the additional cards solely for future credit value is not really worth the hassle of maintaining them. You may also have to use them once every few years to keep them active. I'd go with just one card that you use all the time, and I agree with RonJohn's answer that having a second card as a backup would potentially be useful too.

Comment: "f you are sure [having] credit cards will not change your spending..." (Speaking to the OP) better yet, get *one* card, and find out whether it changes your spending habits. Wait 12 months to get your second card, and by then you'll know more about who you are, and what you can trust yourself with. You don't have to win the race by 22. Even if it takes you 10 years to reach your goal, you'll still be relatively young; so take your time to refine your goals as you go.

Comment: I agree with this answer, except the "slightly" in "I'd say yes, slightly". Credit utilization is a very significant factor in the score. Having more _unused_ available credit actually helps credit score not "slightly" but _a lot_.

Comment: @PhilFrost that's generally true, but it depends on the percentage delta. If you are paying in full every month I'm not sure if $1K usage out of $15K makes much difference compared to $1K out of $25K. But $1K out of $2K vs $1K out of $12K could make a significant difference.

Comment: @TTT what you are saying in the comment is "opening more credit if you already have a lot of unused credit will slightly improve your credit utilization", but what you are saying in the answer is "reducing your credit utilization will only slightly improve your score". These are two very different things.

Comment: @PhilFrost - Does my answer say that? I think I'm making multiple separate points that you may be merging together?

Comment: @TTT I'm telling you what I understand your answer to mean. Do whatever you want with that information.

Answer (score 7):

For many people, opening many credit cards is a recipe for total disaster, because they don't understand that any money they borrow has to be paid back at a high interest rate, and they get themselves in so much debt that they can't find a way out of it. And that WILL destroy your credit score.

Only use a credit card if you have enough money to pay it back completely before you are charged any interest. Never use credit cards for a loan - any loan from your bank will be an awful lot cheaper. If at all possible don't take any loans.

Comment: The question appears to be mainly about the impact on the asker's credit score.

Comment: This is just a rephrasing of the old saying about a fool and his money.

Comment: @jamesqf which is true!

Comment: While this answer is *important* information, especially for anyone asking or finding this question, it doesn't actually answer the question, which is about credit score.

Comment: @user253751 I don't know what question you were reading, the one I read was "Open many credit cards while I am young?" And do you think getting yourself into debt that you can't pay isn't affecting your credit score?

Answer (score 4):

Opening one credit card account may not be a bad idea, so long as you keep spending on it low, and pay it in full every billing cycle. CC Interest is beyond hair-on-fire levels of debt, and should be avoided at all costs.

That all being said, it might be worth looking into why you want good credit, and more importantly when you want good credit.

Credit (and credit score) only truly matter when you are looking to borrow money. Plan out your goals, and figure out when you need to borrow, and for what.

As for raising your credit score, a mix of account types looks much better than just a stack of credit cards. The way you use your credit card(s) (eg. what % of your limit is in use, if you're trending to using more or less than previous time periods) Has a sizeable impact. The amount of recent credit, and how old your credit accounts are also impacts your score. Most importantly, your history of payment on open credit lines has the largest impact. Doing everything else to raise your credit and missing a payment or 2 will lead to a much lower score than just restricting the debt you acquire to what you can afford.

Comment: `CC Interest is beyond hair-on-fire levels of debt` especially for any credit card you would be approved for when you are young and don't have an established credit history. They can border on usury rates.

Comment: @SethR Fun fact: in Islamic banking, ***any*** interest (above 0) is usury.

Comment: With an established credit score over 770+, I can get a CC with ~24.99% APR, or a personal unsecured loan for ~9%. The 9% is STILL disgustingly high, and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Don't know if this is true, but I have heard it said that credit scores are of interest in non-financial areas like on-line dating sites and job applications.

Comment: @GOATNine: But why should the interest rate on a credit card even be of interest?  It might make more sense to use the older term: charge card. You charge stuff because it's more convenient, e.g. if I put gas in my car, I don't have to waste time walking into the store and waiting for a clerk.  Then you pay it off before the due date.

Comment: @jamesqf Where I live you have a debit card for that. Preferably a debit card with an arranged overdraft, so you don't have to worry at the end of the month. Money comes straight from your bank account; no interest paid.

Comment: @jamesqf the interest rate matter because not everyone has perfect discipline, and everyone makes a mistake eventually. It's important to be cognizant to the terms of the charge card, even if those terms should never impact you.
To be honest, I don't ever check the APR myself. I happened to on this one because I was demonstrating the effects of compound interest to my sister in law in excel and wanted a real world example.

Comment: @gnasher729: I still don't understand why anyone would prefer the debit card, which takes money "straight from your bank account" at the time of use, to a credit card that give you an average of 4 weeks or more for that money to stay in your account and work for you,  Plus cash back, of course.  And I don't imagine that pre-arranged overdraft is offered at zero interest, is it?

Comment: @GOATNine: But again, a particular individual's degree of self-discipline is an entirely separate issue.  I think everyone has said, repeatedly, that if the OP is inclined to run up credit card bills that aren't paid off every month, s/he should not get a lot of cards, or even one card with a high limit.

Comment: @jamesqf - yes. Exactly. I find it remarkable that anti-card people actually formed their own cult. "No responsible use of credit cards." Really? Dave Ramsey has a bankruptcy in his history. Who should be preaching about 'responsible'?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things at play in your question. First, the goal -

[image]

This image is from Credit Karma which offers scores from EquiFax and Transunion. They suggest that it takes 11+ accounts in one's history to be 'in the green zone'. FICO reflects this as a mix of accounts. These can be mortgages, equity lines, car leases, store cards, credit cards, etc.

But, we have the hard inquiries. 0-2 is ideal. Too many is a sign that one is having some kind of difficulty and getting new credit in multiple places.

This is from my actual report. The last card I got was 3 years ago. My daughter left for college, and the best airline to use to visit had an affinity card (they all do, it seems). A new card offered a 60,000 mile bonus after some moderate use ($2500 if I recall). The round trip was pretty short, and only cost 20,000 miles. Thus making the bonus worth close to $1000. I offer this to share that shotgunning an effort to get multiple cards makes little sense at this point. Your credit score is best established by researching the best card for your lifestyle now. The month my daughter was born, I got a card that offered 2% cash back into a 529 college savings account. She's a senior, and that account funded over 2 years of her tuition.

Get the first card, make sure it has no annual fee. Live within your budget. Charge what you can afford to pay back when the bill comes in. (in other words, use it only for the regular budgeted expenses). Read all you can about saving, investing, and having a healthy financial mindset. Adding another card over time will make sense once you've established your spending pattern.

It's not tough to find hundreds, if not thousands, of finance bloggers writing about getting out of debt. Read a few of those sites and treat their stories as a warning about what not to do. Banks are not your friend, they will gladly sell you the rope to hang yourself if it will profit them. FICO, and credit scoring is a process the banks use to maximize their own profit, not to help you.

Last - there's a wide range of opinion on this topic. There are those who have 2 favorite quotes "There is no such thing as responsible credit card use" and "Those that use credit cards spend 10-15% more on average due to card use." For a long time alcoholic, there is no level of safe drinking. Those who budget and live within that budget get multiple benefits from running their expenses through their credit cards. For those who maintain a balance month to month with interest adding up, those two statement are true. (Note how I don't speak in absolutes? Personal finance is just that, personal. There is no "one size fits all" solution.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself how the issuers hope those cards might be used, and why?

If you treat them as ordinary credit cards, you stand to lose a lot. CC operators will give you 0% on balance transfers partly because many Users will forget to clear the transferred balance in time but that's small beer

What they really want is "just" to get your every-day business which means they buy money at something close to your jurisdiction's central bank rate and sell it you for more; In this day and age for much, much more. Hooray!

Treating them as investment tools is a very different thing.

If you can pay in without spending, do so… treat them them as savings accounts and spread across the range every penny you can afford. With today's pathetic returns on any investment generally available to you and I, you can't lose by that.

No interest from a credit card is worth exactly the same as no interest from a bank account, in terms of cash returns. So what?

If you have to spend to keep the account, spend the least that costs nothing… IE, use them only as debit cards and carry forward only ever the tiniest amount of credit your contract demands.

17 years down the line, having maintained a positive balance on your standard bank account - what I believe US Americans call a "chequing" account - will serve you as it serves you.

At the same point in time, who thinks having regularly used six or 12 or 18 cards and maintained all of them in credit will not serve you better?

Again, please: Do not use those accounts for credit!